# windows ce 5.0 dll - Can it be fixed address?

Tags: dll, windows-ce, offset

I have been asked by a client to add OpenSSL to their Windows CE 5.0 based product.  They need OpenSSL to operate in FIPS mode, which requires a known address at compile time for the library.  I have no problems if I build an EXE because I can always rely on an base address of 0x10000 for the EXE, which the FIPS mode check uses to validate the EXE.

The issue I am having is that I need the OpenSSL code to be built into a DLL which is called from another DLL which is called by the main app EXE who calls other DLLs.  So how do I know the address of the my DLL runtime?

The only way I know how to make all this work is if the DLL in question pops up a message box or writes to disk the address for one of its functions, which I can then compare to the offset in the map file when I built that DLL and get the base address for the DLL.  Then I can go back with that address, rebuild the OpenSSL stuff, and then rebuild my DLL and it all works.  FIPS mode is enabled because the address specified at compile time is the address in use runtime.

While this seems to solve the issue, I do not like that this base address may change if other DLLs change or if this DLL changes to add or remove code.  But I guess as long as everything is static, this approach might be okay.

My question:

Is there any way to fix the address of a DLL that is loaded runtime?  Or is BIB and ROM my only option here?  Just want to double check if I could be doing something differently.  Right now if any DLL used by my EXE changes, or if my EXE changes to use more or less DLLs, it might change the load address for my DLL which in turn will disable FIPS mode, so I would have to rebuild the OpenSSL library with the new base address and then rebuild my DLL to get working again.  I am trying to avoid that while still running that OpenSSL library code from a DLL, but I'm not sure it is possible.  Other than moving away from CE 5.0, any recommendations?  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [the /BASE linker option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa449701.aspx):

> **/BASE** Sets a base address for the program, overriding the default location
>   for (...) a DLL (at 0x10000000). The operating system first attempts to load a program at its specified or default base address. If sufficient space is not available there, the system relocates the program. To prevent relocation, use the /FIXED option.

If, for whatever reason, the /BASE option doesn't work, an alternative could be to implement a separate OpenSSL exe, and provide a proxy dll to enable clients to communicate with the OpenSSL process.

Comment: Thanks.  I have already tried those options but the address still changes.  I was hoping to avoid the proxy method but I guess that might be my option other option here.